# Moving buttons with animation and changing their position afterwards

Tags: java, android, objectanimator

I am learning Java and Android SDK. I want to create a simple application that is swapping 2 buttons so the left one is moving to the place of right one and v.v. with simple animation. I have tried the ObjectAnimator because I have read that it is moving the views objects permanently. But it's not :-( The objects stays there I mean the left one on the right and v.v. but their getLeft(), getTop() values are the same, and after next animations starts the objects are returning to the start position immediately. I have read that the ObjectAnimator needs some additional function to work properly but in the documentation there is no example :-( I have tried to add the setTranslationX function but it hasn't worked. Could somebody provide me with some simple example of how to do this?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator

"The object property that you are animating must have a setter function (in camel case) in the form of set(). Because the ObjectAnimator automatically updates the property during animation, it must be able to access the property with this setter method. For example, if the property name is foo, you need to have a setFoo() method. If this setter method does not exist, you have three options:
Add the setter method to the class if you have the rights to do so.
Use a wrapper class that you have rights to change and have that wrapper receive the value with a valid setter method and forward it to the original object.
Use ValueAnimator instead."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

try this code:

> public class ActivityStartup extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("hello");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setBehindOffset(100);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);

    View view = G.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
    view.findViewById(R.id.layout_crop).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(G.context, "Crop Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.img_logo).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://example.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    menu.setMenu(view);
}
```

}

> public class G extends Application {

```
public static LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public static Context        context;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    context = getApplicationContext();
}
```

}

main.xml is:

> 

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

menu.xml is:

> 

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_logo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dip"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/hlogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_crop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_crop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crop"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_day"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_day" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Day"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_delete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```